# Running an application's setup.py with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

With Heroku, I can easily deal with deploying traditional distributions of Python apps that need to run `setup.py`. All I have to do is add `-e .` to the `requirements.txt` file.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this with Google App Engine's new flexible VM.

I tried adding `-e .` and `-e /app` to `requirements.txt` but no dice.

```
Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:ac2af9efbff12cd7020c1bfeca2ef4cb4a2c87de30709edcffaf5cd292b5a421" failed: exit status 1
```

Anyone know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the runtime adds requirements.txt by itself before it adds your application code. This is to prevent thrashing the docker cache. See the example dockerfile in the README [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime)

You can switch to a custom runtime and change the order so that `pip install` is run after adding the application code. You can just `gcloud beta app gen-config --custom` to do this.